# Assembly Dependencies not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I've already done the respective things like checking the assembly versions, reinstalling the reference files , etc . But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676/181087).

Comment: thank you soo much .the error has been solved. But the new problem is that , the application is working properly on local host but when I upload it on Filezilla server it's giving the same error

Comment: You should use the Publish feature of Visual Studio to export a compiled web site. Right-click on the project, choose `Publish...` and then fill in the options. You can either publish it directly to an FTP location or to a local directory first and then upload it with an external FTP client. Also, be sure the references in your published `web.config` file are correct and change them in `Web.Debug.config` or `Web.Release.config` if they are not.

Comment: This is may code in MVC Controller:                                                                        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Product(ProductClass Prod,string Category)
        {
                      var cat = (from p in sd.ShoeProducts
                       where p.CID == Category
                       select p).ToList();


            DataSet ds = Prod.GetAllBrands();
            ViewBag.Brands = ds.Tables[0];
            return View(cat.ToList());
        }

Comment: and this is written in view

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var c = "";
        $("#Men").click(function () {
            debugger;
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                c = $(this).attr("value");
            }
        });</script>

Comment: Please don't add code to comments. Instead, you should edit your answer to add the code and any other necessary information. Also, be aware that if you indent by 4 spaces, the code will be formatted automatically.