# ASP.NET MVC 5 application compiling to MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a ASP.NET MVC application using MVC 5 installed through Nuget packages.

Packages.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="ActionMailerNext" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ActionMailerNext.Mvc5" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CsQuery" version="1.3.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Mandrill" version="1.2.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples" version="2.1.0-alpha1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net45" />

  <package id="OpenTok" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PreMailer.Net" version="1.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RestSharpSigned" version="105.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Sendgrid" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SendGrid.SmtpApi" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="UserLockoutEnabledByDefault" value="true" />
    <add key="DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan" value="1" />
    <add key="MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout" value="3" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="IdentitySample.Startup,InnerHour" />       
    <add key="NewProfileImagePath" value="http://innerhour.alightsoftwares.com/ProfileImage/" />          
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1012000"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
      </configuration>
```

Views folder web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Inside .csproj file i have checked all the versions for MVC, webpages, razor are pointing to correct versions.Also i created a new empty mvc5 app and compared the csproj files and found some differences.

My MVC 5 project's csproj file has the below lines extra for dlls in the include directive which are not part of newly created MVC5 webapp.

When i build the solution the MVC version is always 4.0 and the references is referred from the bin folder instead of the packages folder where system.web.mvc with version 5.1.0 is lying and other references are failing which are dependent on MVC 5 instead of MVC 4.
I know that for MVC5 system.web.mvc need not to be in GAC for referencing.

This project is delivered to me by outsourced team so i am completely clueless what could have gone wrong.

I am using windows 7 os and visual studio 2015 community version.

```
<Content Include="bin\ActionMailerNext.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\ActionMailerNext.Mvc5.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\CsQuery.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\EntityFramework.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\InnerHour.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\InnerHour.pdb" />
    <Content Include="bin\Mandrill.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\MCPG.CCA.Util.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\OpenTok.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\Owin.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\PreMailer.Net.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\RestSharp.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\SendGrid.SmtpApi.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\SendGridMail.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Http.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Razor.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Webpages.Deployment.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Webpages.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\System.Web.Webpages.Razor.dll" />
    <Content Include="bin\WebGrease.dll" />
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the main issue is that you are referencing files in the `/bin` folder directly, especially `<Content Include="bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll" />`. You should be referencing them from the `\packages` folder [like this](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider.csproj#L82-L97), which are the files that are supplied by NuGet to reference.

Comment: yeah i am also thinking in this direction.Nuget supplied mvc, webpages, razor, helpers,,, lot of them which are includes in my packages folder.How shall i troubleshoot/workaround-hack  this?And all the dlls that are included are of version other than the version specified by nuget packages.conf.

Comment: yeah, the link that you shared in the comment, the dlls are also referred in the csproj file along with hint path.Damn it is weird why they have added two ways of adding the dlls.Shall i remove some of the dll's from the content include directive and build the solution again.I think that is the only way to find out.

Comment: yeah it worked for me thanks for making me sure that i am going to right direction for troubleshooting. i am back to .net development almost after 1 year after working on open source technologies.Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to edit them by hand as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676/181087). Or alternatively, you could remove all of the above dependencies and re-add them via NuGet and then check them manually and edit them if necessary.

Comment: yeah i got your point.The correct version of the referenced dlls should be mentioned in the hint path of the referenced assembly, which i already mentioned in the above comment that it has both referenced assembly and content include which is definitely weird(why two ways of referring the same dependency).Tomorrow i have a call with outsourced team about and will definitely get to the root of the issue as it almost ate my sunday to figure out what is wrong.Thanks anyway, if i will still have further doubts i will add more comments tomorrow.

Comment: yeah i found out that the outsourced team was using SVN instead of git, as i was on git.But they do have nuget hooked up,,,, can you point more direction?