# Lucene Update not working Index Writer

Tags: vb.net, lucene, lucene.net

I have updated a large application from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.52 and it has broken some indexing and search functions that I have that use Lucene. I updated to the latest NuGet Packages for Lucene and I keep getting the following errors. 
Type 'Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter' is not defined.
Type 'Lucene.Net.Documents.Document' is not defined.
Type 'IndexWriter' is not defined.
To name a few. The search functions were originally written by another developer so I am not completely familiar with it but it looks like they may have moved some namespaces when they updated Lucene to 3.0.3 but I can't find what they updated to. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Code Example Below
References:

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
Imports Lucene.Net
Imports Lucene.Net.Documents
Imports Lucene.Net.Store

Imports Lucene.Net.Index
Imports Lucene.Net.Analysis
```

The Lucene.Net.Store says it doesn't contain any public members.

Example function that says Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter is not defined

```
 Private Function IndexNewDocument(id As String, savePath As String, targetContainer As String, indexer As Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter, b As CloudBlockBlob) As Boolean
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew

    Dim filename As String = ""
    Dim dt As DateTime = Now

    Try
        ' Retrieve the document and pull the metadata for reindexing
        Dim docReturn As DocumentReturn = DocumentDownloadAdapter.GetDocument(_StorageEndpoint, _NewDocumentContainerName, id)
        filename = docReturn.Filename
        dt = docReturn.DateAdded

        ' Get the blob reader for indexing
        Dim docReader As IBlobDocumentReader = FileProcessor.GetBlobDocumentReader(docReturn.FileBytes, docReturn.Filename, savePath)

        ' push the index to the blob storage database
        pushIndexDocument(id, filename, dt, docReader, indexer)

        sw.Stop()
        OnDocumentIndexSuccessful(id, filename, sw.Elapsed)

        Return True
    Catch ex As EmptyPDFException
        CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument", ex, "")

        ' DELETE FILE FROM NEW BLOB INDEX
        Try
            b.Delete()
        Catch exDelete As Exception
            CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument: Problem Deleting blob", exDelete, "")
        End Try

        Try
            Dim username As String = getDocumentUsername(targetContainer, id)
            EmailAdapter.SendExceptionEmail(ex, GetEmailList(ConfigurationHelper.IndexEmailToList), GetEmailList(ConfigurationHelper.IndexEmailCCList), username)
        Catch exEmail As Exception
            CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument: Problem Emailing Exception", exEmail, "")
        End Try

        Return False
    Catch ex As InvalidDocumentTypeException
        CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument", ex, "")

        ' DELETE FILE FROM NEW BLOB INDEX
        Try
            b.Delete()
        Catch exDelete As Exception
            CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument: Problem Deleting blob", exDelete, "")
        End Try

        Try
            Dim username As String = getDocumentUsername(targetContainer, id)
            EmailAdapter.SendExceptionEmail(ex, GetEmailList(ConfigurationHelper.IndexEmailToList), GetEmailList(ConfigurationHelper.IndexEmailCCList), username)
        Catch exEmail As Exception
            CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument: Problem Emailing Exception", exEmail, "")
        End Try

        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        CommonCodeLib.ErrorReport("AzureStorageAccountAdapter.indexDocument", ex.ToString, "")
        sw.Stop()
        OnDocumentIndexFailed(id, filename, sw.Elapsed, ex)

        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I added the code. Thanks!

Comment: Since the code you supplied doesn't reference `IndexWriter`, it is not possible to determine what the problem is based on the question. I suspect based on the error you are getting that you have only upgraded part of your project to Lucene.Net 3.0.3. You need to [manually review the relevant files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676) (project files, config files, and all dependencies) to ensure all of the version numbers match.

Comment: The reference is in the function line. "indexer As Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter", I have re-added all of the references that were originally in the project. I cannot find the namespace that calls the indexWriter. Same with documents.