# Visual Studio 2017 Does Not Discover Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I am running `.NET Framework 4.6.1` to build a test class library where I build `MSTest` tests (`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`). I **can run the tests absolutely fine by going into the folder containing the test project and running `dotnet test`.**

However, VS does NOT discover the tests in the Text Explorer. I have updated every single related NuGet package to latest as recommended in some answer to this problem:

[image]

I have also tried both `Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> x86` and `x64`.

I always get the following error:

> [1/10/2018 5:01:03 PM Warning] Test run will use DLL(s) built for
>   framework Framework45 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) will not be
>   part of run:

What can cause this? If it helps, all my co-workers have the same issue, and only on this solution.

This is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.2` project.

Edit: csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>    
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform" Version="14.0.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.7.99" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CommonHelpers\CommonTestHelpers.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ks-systems\ks-systems.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{82a7f48d-3b50-4b1e-b82e-3ada8210c358}" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Edit 2:

Looks like changing to `x86` / `x64` in the menu bar doesn't change my `.csproj`. I changed it by hand to `x86` - this got them discovered. Now all 56 tests are failing with the following:

> Message: Unable to create instance of class cm-tools.Tests.Services.TripScholarshipServiceTest. Error: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CtsPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format..

Note that making the change above causes the tests to be discovered, and also causes all of them to FAIL, including when trying `dotnet test` from console, which works without the change.

Comment: You use AspNetCore *but* you target .NET framework non-core ? (4.6.1)

Comment: @Pac0 Yea - good call, that's how it was set up. I think part of the (not really reasonable) reasoning is that we write NuGet packages for internal stuff, so we need to target that Framework that the packages are written in. I am out of my element here. I am going to go try changing the target framework. Edit: Tried it, cleaned, rebuilt, no change.

Comment: I suggest [reviewing your `.csproj` files manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676/). The project could have invalid references and/or conditional logic that is not visible and/or changeable in Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, if you need to share DLLs between .NET Framework 4.5+ and .NET Core, consider targeting [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). If targeting < .NET Framework 4.5, then create multi-targeted builds/NuGet packages.

Comment: Can you show your test project’s `.csproj` file?

Comment: Can you try removing the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform` package and switching back to x64? Btw. also try to move the `<PlatformTarget>` node into the general unconditioned `<PropertyGroup>`.