# NANT Issues with Version Mismatch of NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nant, nuget-package-restore

### Problem

(Edited 2/16/2018 - Purpose of Reviving Question)

I have been working with a project (using C# and Visual Studio 2015) for which I create an installer for by having Jenkins checkout the develop branch, restore all NuGet packages, and then have NANT to create an .msi installer. Until recently, there has been no problems with this setup; however, while attempting to test out a new feature, I ran into an issue where the project was unable to load a specific assembly reference.

Upon investigation, I found that log4Net version 2.0.0 (aka 1.2.11.0) was the cause. Further investigation showed that the workspace had all of the correct versions of all the .dlls for all references. To add further complications, I have tried all of the following troubleshoot methods:

- Tried enforcing 'SpecificVersion' as 'true' and as 'false'
- Went through every package.config, web.config, app.config, and .csproj file and manually changed all references I could find of log4Net to reference version 2.0.0
- Uninstalling/reinstalling log4net in all aspects of the solution that utilized it

Despite all of these investigative/troubleshooting methodologies, the .msi file still contains/installs the wrong .dll for log4Net. The .dll that is installed is version 1.2.9.0, which causes the application to break because it is expecting a higher version than what is available. At first, I was going to simply leave it at just dropping the correct .dll into the installed folder; however, this solution isn't viable and I'm starting to see cases in which a similar issue is affecting other nuget packages.

### Question

Does anyone know what would cause NANT to pull the wrong version of a NuGet package, and how to resolve this?

Comment: Note that `.config` files may also contain rogue references to outdated versions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676).

Comment: @NightOwl888 Ah, thank you for this info. I will see if the problem lies there