# Type not found Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in .NET Standard project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I am having a total nightmare getting Entity Framework Core working in my .NET standard project!  I am using .NET Standard 2

I can install the package fine (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)

However, when I build my application although it compiles, I get the error below

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Has anyone ever had this?  I wasnt expecting this to be such a pain just to use Entity Framework in .NET Standard lol

I cant see any dlls related to this in my output folders

My application is hosted within service fabric, but I am not sure thats anything to do with it

Paul

Comment: "The error below", what error? I only see information of a DLL.

Comment: Whoops - will edit question - its a type not found error

Comment: Common suggestion for these problems: clean, rebuild, close VS and open again, delete .suo file, delete .vs folder. Have you tried those? Also, do you get a build succeeded or failed in the output window?

Comment: Yep no luck with those, I get a build succeeded the interesting thing is not seeing any reference to the package anywhere, not even the packages folder.  If I look at the package in the project it points to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\2.0.1

Comment: Do you have a NuGet dependency to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer but not to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore? Since the SqlServer depends on the first one, it downloads it automatically but sometimes fail to reference

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you could be onto something there am out now but will check later

Comment: I didnt have that package, I have it now but still doesnt work and still cannot find any of the packages/dlls related to EF Core within my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is a bug either with Nuget or Visual Studio

I ended up having to manually copy all the dlls!!

Comment: Most likely it is just a version conflict, as is often the case when changing dependencies. You just need to [manually review the dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676/) to find and fix the problem.

Comment: None of the assemblies for the packages got copied into the output folder at all I am having to go one by one to find them and copy them into the output folder really time consuming and tedious!

Comment: You are aware there is a [`CopyToOutputDirectory` setting in MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) that can be turned on or off, aren't you?

Comment: How do I set that for a .net standard project?

Comment: It is the same as the old `.csproj` format. But hold on a minute - when files aren't copied to the output directory, that is a sign there is a build error preventing the build from occurring. You should [turn on verbose setting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/09/28/cranking-up-the-build-verbosity-in-the-ide/) to see if you can find the details of the build issue (assuming they don't already appear in the build errors section).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this into your .csproj file which contains reference to the

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```