# WCF - Return .NET Standard library objects

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library which defines EF entities and Views, and it is referenced by some other .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.7.1 projects without problems.
But I'm not able to do the same with a WCF 4.7.1 one, using VS 2017, which returns these views. Error:

```
"Couldn't get dependencies for reference project"
```

What is the solution for this?

EDIT: Actually I just noticed I can't reference ANY library. It seems it got nothing to do with .NET Standard.

Comment: What version of the .NET Framework is used in that WCF project? Is this in VS 2015 or 2017?

Comment: 4.7.1 WCF and VS 2017

Comment: Looks like its time to [manually review your project and config file settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35991676/).